# QT Bar Chart/Graph for QT Commercial 5.6

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, graph, charts

I am re-engineering an aspect of current existing software in C++ that uses Qt 5.6.  I am trying to create a bar chart that can represent the data stored in a table of int(s).

I used the Qt example in my code for a bar chart:

Includes:

```
#include <QChart>
#include <QBarSet>
#include <QBarSeries>
```

I attempted to put the includes in the .cpp file however for some reason the classes were not recognized unless they were forward declared so I moved the includes to the header file such that:

```
#include <QChart>
#include <QBarSet>
#include <QBarSeries>
class QChart;
class QBarSet;
class QBarSeries;
```

Code:

```
QBarSet *mainSet = new QBarSet("Data"); 
.
.
.
```

(I'll leave the rest of the code out since it really isn't important for the answer)

With the above code (`new QBarSet("Data")`) QBarSet is underlined in red in visual studio stating "incomplete type is not allowed".

I figure the issue is due to the fact I am trying to use Qt 5.6 for the graphs so I refereed to their website.

From Qt's Qt Charts 2.1.0 website:

> In Qt 5.6 release the module binaries will still be available only
>   with the commercial packages.

That is where I am stuck.

Anyone know my issue or how I can get Qt bar charts for qt 5.6 (if possible)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this resource:
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-index.html

Stupid mistake, I was importing the wrong files. I removed all the includes that I had in my header file and put the following and it worked fine.

Header:

```
#include <QtCharts>
using namespace QtCharts;
```

Source:

```
QBarSet *mainSet = new QBarSet("Data"); 
.
.
.
```